# How to add vertices to loop without breaking it?

Tags: modeling, vertices, loop

I have a missing part in my mesh (with subdiv modifier) where was a vertex:
[image]

I need to add vertex just in center and not to break the loop. How can I do this?
I've tried to use `ctrl+F` combination with further `loop cut` and merging two verticies at center, but the loop is breaking and subdiv affect differently at this part:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Select the 2 opposite edges and press Ctrl F > Grid Fill?

Comment: @moonboots which edges exactly? I've tried left and right or top and down - loop is still breaking. And I didn't get it - should I use Ctrl F and Grid Fill or I should use just one of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE

Select these

[image]

F

[image]

Subdivide

[image]

select

[image]

F

[image]

select

[image]

F

select

[image]

F

[image]

Select (if you have F2 add-on enabled, else select 4 vertices)

[image]

F

[image]

F

[image]

select

[image]

F

result:

[image]

---

i would select these points:

[image]

and then grid fill.

[image]

Comment: Grid fill is still breaking the loop and look exactly as my result at my 2 screenshot, as I can see.

Comment: then pls provide blend file, because we cannot "guess" what positions your vertices have

Comment: I've added it to question. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Select the 2 opposite edges and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*:

[image]